# Errors when compiling C program with pointers

Tags: c, pointers

When I run this on my computer I get compile errors. However, I did copy it straight from a tutorial I found on the Internet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(){
    int i = 9;
    clrscr();

    printf("The value of i is: %d\n", i);
    printf("The address of i is: %u\n", &i);
    printf("The value at the address of i is: %d\n", *(&i));

    getch();
}
```

The errors:

```
$ cc "-Wall" -g    ptrex6.c   -o ptrex6
ptrex6.c:7:19: error: conio.h: No such file or directory
ptrex6.c:9: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
ptrex6.c: In function ‘main’:
ptrex6.c:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘clrscr’
ptrex6.c:14: warning: format ‘%u’ expects type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
ptrex6.c:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getch’
make: *** [ptrex6] Error 1
```

Comment: *Throw away the tutorial.* `void main()` is not valid C.

Comment: You should read the error messages, as it is pointing out multiple problems to you: `main` should be declared as `int main()` not `void main()`; your include path seems to be wrong as `conio.h` was not found; your format is incorrect -- a pointer value is not an unsigned int (`%u`), you probably want `%p` instead.

Comment: ConIO is a dos library, what kind of machine are you compiling this on?

Comment: And yeah, you SHOULD learn interpreting compiler messages.

Comment: The tutorial was run on a Windows box. I have a Linux box. I just found out that I do not have <conio.h> on my system.

Comment: @MattJoiner: The language standard specifies that, on a hosted implementation, `main` shall be declared as either `int main(void)`, `int main(int argc, char **argv)` (or equivalent), or *in some other implementation-defined manner*, meaning that the implementation **must** explicitly document any other legal signatures.  Unless the OP's implementation explicitly lists `void main()` as a legal signature, the behavior will be undefined.

Comment: Yet another data point in favor of my theory that 99% of online C tutorials are *crap* and should be ignored (if not set on fire).  Aside from assuming a specific DOS/Win implementation and a bogus return type for `main`, it uses the `%u` conversion specifier to print a pointer value, which is a mistake (`%u` expects the corresponding argument to be of type `unsigned long`, not `int *`).  Find an authoritative dead-trees reference like "The C Programming Language, 2nd ed." by Kernighan & Ritchie or "C Programming: A Modern Approach" by King.

Comment: @John `%u` expects `unsigned int`, not `unsigned long`, important difference nowadays.

Comment: @DanielFischer: derp.  You're absolutely correct.  Must've popped another synapse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mistakes:

1. `conio.h` is not a standard C header. It might be unavailable on your system. Nevertheless, it's not needed for printf(). That's why `stdio.h` is here. Remove it, and also remove clrscr(). It won't work without the conio libraries. By doing this, you'll able to compile your file, since the other messages are "just" warnings, not errors.
2. Change your `main()` function's return type to `int` and return 0. That's what the C standard specifies. **You want this.**
3. Use the `%d` format specifier in place of `%u`. As the compiler message directly points out, %u is for unsigned integers, and `int` is explicitly signed. For integers >= 2 ^ 31, you'll experience strange behavior problems.
4. You're using a wrong specifier one more time. Use `%p` for addresses/pointers, not %u/%d/whatever.
5. Don't explicitly believe/copy-paste from tutorials. Tutorials are not for copy-pasting, they're to be thought of and learnt from.

Comment: the return statement at the end of `main` is not mandatory so I would not call it a mistake.

Comment: I would since if you don't use it, you'll get used to return void from non-void functions and those wouldn't be corrected by the compiler (as does crt0 if one does not return from main()), and they **will** crash.

Comment: I have done what you suggested and changed getch() to getchar(). Now I have fewer errors.

Comment: @ouah Well, it is a mistake in C<99.

Comment: in the current standard it is equivalent as returning `0` and in C89 as returning an `int` of an unspecified value.

Comment: then it may be just GCC who is (-)pedantic... :)

Answer (score 4):

You must have used a fairly old book/example. The conio.h file was used on MS-DOS systems. Your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 9;

    printf("The value of i is: %d\n", i);
    printf("The address of i is: %p\n", (void*)&i);
}
```

Comment: `&i` has to be casted to `void *` otherwise it is undefined behavior.

Comment: You're right! Sorry slipped past me.

Comment: What about the clrscr() function?

Comment: The clrscr() function is/was declared in the conio.h file, which you don't get on any modern system as far as i know. You can use any other library that provides help handling the console (ncurses). But i would recommend learning the c basics first.

Comment: @ouah : I'm wondering : Why the need to cast `&i` to `void *`? `&i` is already `int *`, and `int *` is an address, nothing more nothing less. Looking at printf's docs online, I see no mention of such need for the explicit cast ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html , http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx ). Do you have a source you could point at?

Comment: You can look it up at many places, e.g. here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html. The argument to a "%p" format should be a (void*).

Comment: @paercebal yes, on `p` conversion specifier, here is what the mighty Standard says: (C99, 7.19.6.1p8) "The argument shall be a pointer to void."

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to print a pointer value in C:

```
printf("The address of i is: %p\n", (void *) &i);
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated by **[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h)**

> conio.h is a C header file used in **old MS-DOS compilers** to create text
>   user interfaces. It is not described in The C Programming Language
>   book, and it is **not part of the C standard library, ISO C nor is it
>   defined by POSIX**.